# Updating a primary key value on grails gorm

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm wondering if I can change a value of <del>a primary key</del> member of a composite primary key in a Grails Domain class? For example having this domain:

```
class StudentHistory implements Serializable {
    String studentNumber
    String schoolYear
    Integer yearLevel
    String section
    Float average
    String status

    static mapping = {
        ...
        id composite: ["studentNumber", "schoolYear", "yearLevel", "section"]
        ...
    }
}
```

Let say, On the `schoolYear: "2014-2015"`, a certain `yearLevel: 1` student with  `studentNumber: "2011-488-MN-0"` transferred section from `section: "1D"` to `section: "1N"`. Now to perform this record update, we do something similar inside a `service`:

```
StudentHistory record = StudentHistory.find {
    eq("studentNumber", "2014-488-MN-0")
    eq("schoolYear", "2014-2015")
    eq("yearLevel", 1)
    eq("section", "1D")
}

record.setSection("1N")

record.save(flush: true, insert: false)
```

The problem is that the update on the primary key doesn't take effect but when I tried to update other non-Primary fields such as `average` and `status`, updating them works fine (I tried performing an `SQL` directly on the database to confirm). How can I update primary keys?

---

**PS:** Now, based on this design, I know some will suggest that why not just create another record, then just fetch the record that has been last entered? But what I am **required to do is to update that composite primary key** instead.

---

**PPS:** Please don't suggest on removing the old instance, and create a new one, copying the old details except for the `section`. I cannot do that since many tables are connected to this table.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on: "the update on the primary key doesn't take effect". How are you confirming it has not taken effect? And, could you please also say whether the above code is in a Service or Controller. Thanks. :)

Comment: @IStevenson I had perfomed an update (inside a service) on a primary and non primary fields, checking on the DB if it works. Updating a primary field on grails does not work, compared to updating a non primary field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a good practice to avoid changing primary keys. Primary key is a unique identifier of an object and changing it effectively means creating a new object. So if your composite primary key is mutable (or can mutate) then you should use a surrogate key - an artificial primary key. At the same time you can create a unique constraint on the 4 fields currently being your primary key.

In your case it would be:

```
static mapping = {
   ...
}

static constraints = {
   studentNumber(unique: ["schoolYear", "yearLevel", "section"])
}
```

Hope it makes sense.